# EJB 3 Eager loading

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb, lazy-loading

I work With EJB 3. I have Base class A and there are dependency classes B,C,D

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<B> bs;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<C> cs;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<D> ds;

}
```

I have question. How can I load all tables eagerly? I want to use `em.find(A.class, id);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution of my question .

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<B> bs;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<C> cs;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<D> ds;

}
```

solution is @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT) . There is a good article about

[Hibernate  Fetching Strategies](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-fetching-strategies-examples/)

Comment: From Hibernate documentation: *We have two orthogonal notions here: when is the association fetched and how is it fetched. It is important that you do not confuse them. We use fetch to tune performance.*  When you're talking about eager fetching, you're asking when to fetch (`FetchType.EAGER` or `FetchType.LAZY`) not how they are fetched (`@Fetch`).

Answer (score 1):

You must use the **fetch** attribute in the OneToMany annotation so:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<B> bs;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<C> cs;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<D> ds;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply . but fetch = FetchType.EAGER can have only one dependeny

Comment: You could put the fetch = FetchType.EAGER in each relationship in your class tree hierarchy.

Comment: I have not tree hierarchy